# On iOS 8, how do I turn on spell check without turning on Auto Correct?

Tags: spellcheck, autocorrect

On iOS 8, how do I turn on spell check without turning on Auto Correct? I just want the red line to appear on words. But autocorrect is terrible and ruins most everything I say. So I just want spell check only. But when I turn off autocorrect then spell check turns off also. How do I fix that?

I'm on iOS 8.3 on a 5S.

Comment: did you try "Settings--General--Keyboard--Predictive. Turns off" and it is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Settings` ➙ `General` ➙ `Keyboard`:

Turn off `Auto-Correction`

Make sure `Check Spelling` (at the bottom of that same screen) is on

Your iDevice will no longer automatically correct misspelled words, but it will highlight them for you. As far as I know this is the only way to have spell-checking on without the Auto-Correct feature.

Comment: It's actually "Keyboard" not "Keyboards" but thanks! The "Check Spelling" option is off the bottom of the screen on iOS 8. I don't know why they had to hide it down there :(

Answer (score 0):

Turn on autocorrect, then turn on Check Spelling. Then turn off autocorrect again. That might turn on spell checking without autocorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your keyboard settings and add "English" to your keyboards. The red line will detect misspelled English words.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all above but it didn't work - finally turned off predictive and turned on and now my spell check is working

Answer (score -2):

Predictive was off. Turned it on and now I have my spell check back. And I turned auto correction off.